# Slick carousel - trouble removing bottom margin

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox, slick.js

I'm trying to build a fullscreen, responsive, 3-slides carousel using Slick and flexbox.

Each slides look like this :

```
<div class="carousel-slide">
    <div class="carousel-yellow flexbox-column flexbox-space-between">
       <div class="title-container flexbox-column flexbox-center">
         <div class="carousel-title">AAA</div>
         <div class="carousel-subtitle">aaa</div>
       </div>
       <img src="img/blabla.gif" class="gif-carousel"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Taken separately each slide has a good layout, but as soon as I call

```
$('.intro-carousel').slick({
  arrows:false,
  infinite:false,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidsToScroll: 1,
})
```

the slides are no longer fullscreen and there is a white bar at the bottom of each slides.

I already tried playing with `min-height` and `min-width` and many other things without any success.

here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x244vj8g/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use viewport based units instead of percentage:

```
.carousel-slide {
  height: 100vh;
}
```